# Abnormal response time behaviour

Tags: python, webserver, locust, rasa, sanic

I've deployed a chatbot application ([rasa](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa)) at a certain endpoint and am using locust to stress test it. I have a single user (with 1 hatch rate) and am sending random sentences to the above endpoint to benchmark the application. Each time the server receives a request, the NLP engine tries to classify the intent and then responds back with an appropriate reply.

The results from locust are quite abnormal to my understanding. Even when the number of users is constant (1), the response time keeps on increasing. Is there any explanation for this behaviour? I'm attaching the obtained plots herewith.

[image: Locust runtime statistics]

Comment: Have you checked server logs and resource usage? You may also check client resource usage. Increasing CPU/memory/network usage on either side can effect response times.

Comment: See https://github.com/locustio/locust/wiki/FAQ#increase-my-request-raterps , particularly point 2.

Comment: I have 4 cores on the server machine and am deploying 4 sanic workers. The overall cpu utilisation stays under 50% across all cores.

Comment: You’ll want to increase the number of users to saturate your system. But there seems to be some a bottleneck even now.